# finding difference between dates based on a criteria

Tags: r

Consider this dataset:

`mydf <- data.frame(churn_indicator = c(0,0,1,0,1),
                     resign_date = c(NA,NA,"2011-01-01",NA,"2012-02-01"),
                     join_date = c("2001-01-01","2001-03-01","2002-04-02",
                                          "2003-09-01","2005-05-10"))`

The task is to calculate a vector 'length' which is resign_date - join_date for churn_indicator=1 and Sys.Date()-join_date for churn_indicator =0.

I have already figured out how to do this using a for loop but I want to use something that more efficient(the apply family maybe). Also, is it possible to do this using dplyr's mutate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution :

```
# convert column from factor/characters to Date (if not already done)
mydf$resign_date <- as.Date(mydf$resign_date)
mydf$join_date <- as.Date(mydf$join_date)

# compute the date differences
days_churn1 <- as.numeric(difftime(mydf$resign_date,mydf$join_date,units='days'))
days_churn0 <- as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),mydf$join_date,units='days'))

# set to zero the values where churn indicator is not what we want
days_churn1[mydf$churn_indicator==0]<-0
days_churn0[mydf$churn_indicator==1]<-0

# sum the two vectors
mydf$length <- days_churn1+days_churn0

> mydf
  churn_indicator resign_date  join_date length
1               0        <NA> 2001-01-01   5997
2               0        <NA> 2001-03-01   5938
3               1  2011-01-01 2002-04-02   3196
4               0        <NA> 2003-09-01   5024
5               1  2012-02-01 2005-05-10   2458
```

Alternatively, you can combine some operations using ifelse :

```
# convert column from factor/characters to Date  (if not already done)
mydf$resign_date <- as.Date(mydf$resign_date)
mydf$join_date <- as.Date(mydf$join_date)

mydf$length <- 
as.numeric(
  ifelse(mydf$churn_indicator==1,
         difftime(mydf$resign_date,mydf$join_date,units='days'),
         difftime(Sys.Date(),mydf$join_date,units='days')
))
```